# how to get hash key for linkedIn account in android using eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, hash, key, linkedin-api

I have tried hash key using .android debug key but still not getting my LinkedIn app connected with my App.
And also getting error like when i link with my Facebook App, LinkedIn also showing linked automatically.
Am i attach Facebook hash key in LinkedIn Account?
Please help me to get the correct hash key for eclipse specially.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 public void generateHashkey(){
    try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                PACKAGE,
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());

             Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

Comment: i need to provide SHA key? or direct paste this code in my App coding

Comment: Direct Past this code,  U will get Keyhash in Log cat
just call generateHashkey() in oncreate in your activity

Comment: What is PACKAGE? ...need to replace this with my app package details?

Comment: yes you need To replace PACKAGE with your package name

Comment: use  getPackageName() instent of PACKAGE

Comment: Thank you so much for your help .

Comment: is this key same for Facebook?.. will i get any error if i use that key for Facebook integration?